# c - Write on a string but every k bytes

Tags: c, string, pointers, calloc

the exercise gives me a main that prints the string list this way, that is, knows that every MAX_NAME_LENGTH has a meaningful name and prints it.

```
#define MAX_NAME_LENGTH 32
#define DIM 4

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {  
    char *list=calloc((MAX_NAME_LENGTH+1),sizeof(char));
    edit(&list);

    int len=strlen(list);
    printf("strlen list %ld\n",strlen(list));

    int nusers = len / (MAX_NAME_LENGTH+1);
    int p=0;

    printf("user online list:\n");
    for(int i=0,p=0;i<nusers; ++i, p+=(MAX_NAME_LENGTH+1)) {
        printf(" %s\n", &list[p]);
    }

    free(list);

    return 0;
}
```

What I can not do is fill in the string correctly, even if the  string is allocated length `DIM*(MAX_NAME_LENGTH+1)`, when I'm going to make a copy the length is less than MAX_NAME_LENGTH, how to do it?

This is edit function which I use to fill the string list

```
int edit(char** list){
    int i;
    char *array[DIM];
    int offset=0;
    for(i=0;i<DIM;i++){
        array[i]=calloc((MAX_NAME_LENGTH+1),sizeof(char));
    }

    strncpy(array[0],"try",MAX_NAME_LENGTH+1);
    printf("array: %s len %ld\n",array[0],strlen(array[0]));

    strncpy(array[1],"test",MAX_NAME_LENGTH+1);
    printf("array: %s len %ld\n",array[1],strlen(array[1]));

    strncpy(array[2],"test5",MAX_NAME_LENGTH+1);
    printf("array: %s len %ld\n",array[2],strlen(array[2]));

    strncpy(array[3],"testone",MAX_NAME_LENGTH+1);
    printf("array: %s len %ld\n",array[3],strlen(array[3]));

    *list=realloc(*list,DIM*(MAX_NAME_LENGTH+1));
    for(i=0;i<DIM;i++){
        strncpy(*list+offset,array[i],MAX_NAME_LENGTH+1);
        offset=offset+MAX_NAME_LENGTH+1;
        printf("list: %s len %ld\n",*list,strlen(*list));
    }


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `%ld` is improper for the return of `strlen` which is `size_t`, use `%zu` instead. (though both are for printing 8-byte values, you will have negative values printed if the sign-bit was ever set -- which would be a really long string). You cannot use `strlen (*list)` as `*list` will have multiple intervening `'\0'` characters terminating the `strlen` scan for the end of string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are filling in the array (I hesitate to call it a string, because it actually contains 4) the way you expect.  The problem comes when you try to get its length in `main`:

```
int len=strlen(list);
```

The `strlen` function counts characters until the first null byte.  What you have here however is 4 strings embedded in an array with null bytes separating them.  So `strlen` stops counting at the first null byte.

To illustrate, here is a simplified version of what your array contains:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------
| 't' | 'r' | 'y' |  0  |  0  | 't' | 'e' | 's' | 't' |  0  |  ...
-------------------------------------------------------------
```

The actual length of the array is what was malloc'ed in the function, so use that instead:

```
int len=DIM*(MAX_NAME_LENGTH+1);
```

You're also not printing correctly in `edit`:

```
offset=offset+MAX_NAME_LENGTH+1;
printf("list: %s len %ld\n",*list,strlen(*list));
```

You use `offset` when copying the strings, so use it here too when printing.

```
printf("list: %s len %ld\n",*list+offset,strlen(*list+offset));
offset=offset+MAX_NAME_LENGTH+1;
```

Answer (score 0):

The `printf()` is always printing just the first word in `*list`. You need to add `offset` there as well:

```
printf("list: %s len %ld\n",*list+offset,strlen(*list+offset));
```

Answer (score 0):

when coding, simple is always better:

Suggest the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX_NAME_LENGTH 32
#define DIM 4

int main( void ) 
{  
    char list[ DIM ][ MAX_NAME_LENGTH +1 ] = 
    {
        "try",
        "test",
        "test5",
        "testone"
    };

    puts("user online list:\n");
    for( size_t i=0; i<DIM; ++i ) 
    {
        printf(" %s\n", list[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

which yields the following output:

```
user online list:

 try
 test
 test5
 testone
```